# Extend Activity to AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android

Sorry if my question is dublicated, but I can't (or dont know how to google) find answer. I want to use `rxlifecycle-navi` library in order to bind rxjava to lifecycle, so I need to extends `NaviActivity` class. The problem is that `NaviActivity` class extends `Activity` and I need to extends `AppCompatActivity` for `toolbar`. How can I achieve this elegant without trying to change source code of library? I found [article](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/how-to-add-toolbar-to-an-activity-which-doesn-t-extend-appcompatactivity-a07c026717b3#.7n6rqv5zd) how to do it via `AppCompatDelegate`, but is doesnt look flexible enought. I suppose it is general problem, that I cant extends 2 classes.

My `BaseActivity` at the moment:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends NaviActivity implements AppCompatCallback {

private final ActivityLifecycleProvider provider = NaviLifecycle.createActivityLifecycleProvider(this);

public AppCompatDelegate delegate;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this);
    delegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {

}

@Override
public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public ActionMode onWindowStartingSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
    return null;
}}
```

And another class:

```
public class CarWashesActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_washes);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    delegate.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    delegate.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution, create your own `NaviAppCompatActivity` in `com.trello.navi.component` package.

```
package com.trello.navi.component;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import com.trello.navi.Event;
import com.trello.navi.Listener;
import com.trello.navi.NaviComponent;
import com.trello.navi.internal.NaviEmitter;

public class NaviAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NaviComponent {

  private final NaviEmitter base = NaviEmitter.createActivityEmitter();

  @Override public boolean handlesEvents(Event... events) {
    return base.handlesEvents(events);
  }

  @Override public <T> void addListener(Event<T> event, Listener<T> listener) {
    base.addListener(event, listener);
  }

  @Override public <T> void removeListener(Listener<T> listener) {
    base.removeListener(listener);
  }

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    base.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    base.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
  }

  @Override protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    base.onStart();
  }

  @Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    base.onResume();
  }

  @Override protected void onPause() {
    base.onPause();
    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override protected void onStop() {
    base.onStop();
    super.onStop();
  }

  @Override protected void onDestroy() {
    base.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    base.onRestart();
  }

  @Override protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    base.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }

  @Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    base.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
  }

  @Override protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    base.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    base.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
  }

  @Override protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    base.onNewIntent(intent);
  }

  @Override public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    base.onBackPressed();
  }

  @Override public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    base.onAttachedToWindow();
  }

  @Override public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    base.onDetachedFromWindow();
  }

  @Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    base.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  }

  @Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    base.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }

  @Override public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
      @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
  }
}
```

Reference:
search for "NaviAppCompatActivity" on https://github.com/trello/navi

Comment: It is good solution, thx, but I was wondering if there is another. Bcs it is not flexible 2, what if the source code of library will change or I simply cant look to source code?

Comment: Umm... it appears to me that the `trello/navi` library [already supports the `NaviAppCompatActivity`](https://github.com/trello/navi/blob/master/navi/src/main/java/com/trello/navi/component/support/NaviAppCompatActivity.java) in the library itself. You don't even have to do the copying that I did.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `AppCompatNaviActivity` extending `AppCompatActivity`. Then add all code provided in `NaviActivity` into `AppCompatNaviActivity`.

Now whenever you need to extend `NaviActivity`, extend `AppCompatNaviActivity` which will provide all awesome features of `AppCompatActivity` and also of `NaviActivity`.

Its a little hack but hope this will help you out.